# Error in loop: Attempted to access F(2); index out of bounds because numel(F)=1

Tags: matlab

I have problems with my code. It says:

```
Attempted to access F(2); index out of bounds because numel(F)=1.
```

An my code is:

```
function Punto3
    global p n E d Vm rugo
    e=0.001:0.02:1;
    E=e*10^-3;
    d=0.01;
    Vm= 10 ;
    p= 998.3;
    n=1.002*10^-3;
    rugo=length(E);

    xo=5;

    f=fsolve(@(F)ecuacion(F),xo);
end

function resp=ecuacion(F)
    global E d re rugo p Vm n
    re=(d*p*Vm)/n;
    ecu = zeros ([1 rugo]);
    for i=1:rugo;

        ecu(i)=-2*log10(((E(i)/d)/3.7)+(2.51/(re*(F(i)^0.5))))-(1/(F(i)^(0.5)));

    end

    resp=ecu;
end
```

I can't find the error; please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arises because your initial guess is a scalar, but `F` is assumed to be a vector of length `rugo` in `ecuacion`.  From the [`documentation`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html#input_argument_x0): "`fsolve` uses the number of elements in and size of `x0` to determine the number and size of variables that `fun` accepts."  So changing the initialization of your guess to

```
xo=5*ones(size(e));
```

will not generate an out-of-bounds error.

---

Concerning the physics of your problem, a friction factor of `5` is rather large for most applications I can think of.  A guess of `0.1` usually works better for me.  Further, I've found that solving for `sqrt(F(i))` and then squaring the solution avoids the worry of complex solutions from the iterative methods in `fsolve`.  So changing the `for`-loop code to

```
function resp=ecuacion(Fsqrt)
...
ecu(i)=-2*log10(((E(i)/d)/3.7)+(2.51/(re*(Fsqrt(i)))))-(1/(Fsqrt(i)));
```

and then the main function output to

```
f=fsolve(@(F)ecuacion(F),xo).^2;
```

should be more robust.

Comment: Thanks, It was really helpful :D